Best strategy to keep backup mirrored on 3 different hard drives on Linux: rsync? mergerfs? something else?
Let's says I have a server and 3 different hard drives.
I want to know what are the pros and cons of different backup strategies. Here are the requirements:

I want that a new file is being automatically copied on the each of the 3 hard drives.
I want them to be individually usable, meaning, if I remove one (or all) of them from the server, I want to be able to read it/them out of the box straight ahead (without having to setup a software layer on top such as RAID).
If I remove one of the 3 hard drives (to keep one of the backups off-site), I want the system still to be functioning and mirroring the backup-data on the 2 remaining hard drives.
I want the solution not to rely on commercial software.
It has to run on Linux and the file system of the hard drives should be ext4.

What do you think of the best strategies:

use rsync with one master hard drives (e.g. HDD_A) and have a script which copies the files on the 2 remaining hard drives (HDD_A -> HDD_B and HDD_A -> HDD_C)
use something like mergerfs (which I have never used so far) and setup a unique file system which mirrors data on the 3 different hard drives simultaneously (is this solution at all possible)?
something else?

